# python string change character in string before certain character

Tags: python, string

I have this url and want to change the px value from 160 to 500. How can I do it without knowing the index of the character? I tried it with replace function

```
https://someurl.com//img_cache/381a58s7943437_037_160px.jpg?old
```

what I want:

```
https://someurl.com//img_cache/381a58s7943437_037_500px.jpg?old
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Maybe try regex to capture a group before, the number, and the group after, then constructing a string with the new value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regexp here `\d+(?=px)` finds the digits that come before `px`, and they are then replaced by whatever you put in the argument `new_res`.

```
import re

string = "https://someurl.com//img_cache/381a58s7943437_037_160px.jpg?old"
new_res = "500"
out = re.sub("\d+(?=px)", new_res, string)

print(out)
```

Output:

```
https://someurl.com//img_cache/381a58s7943437_037_500px.jpg?old
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

s = 'https://someurl.com//img_cache/381a58s7943437_037_160px.jpg?old'
s = re.sub(r'_\d+px\.', '_500px.', s)
```

```
>>> s
'https://someurl.com//img_cache/381a58s7943437_037_500px.jpg?old'
```

Comment: This cuts out the `.` between `px` and `jpg`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex pattern that looks for one or more digits, with a positive lookahead that asserts that what immediately follows is the substring `"px.jpg"`:

```
import re

url = "https://someurl.com//img_cache/381a58s7943437_037_160px.jpg?old"

pattern = "\\d+(?=px.jpg)"

print(re.sub(pattern, "540", url))
```

Output:

```
https://someurl.com//img_cache/381a58s7943437_037_540px.jpg?old
>>>
```